# packaging an overloaded function (like std::stoll) into std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, std-function

I'm having difficulty packaging `std::stoll` into a `std::function`. The naive

```
std::function<std::int64_t(std::string const&)> obj = std::stoll;
```

fails because `std::stoll` is an overload of two functions (something cppreference doesn't mention *[at the time of asking]*), one taking `std::string` the other `std::wstring` as first argument. So how am I getting what I want?

I know that I could instead use a lambda that calls `std::stoll`, but I'm looking for a solution of the form

```
auto parser = ???
std::function<std::int64_t(std::string const&)> obj{parser};
```

Comment: ...something cppreference *didn't* mention

Comment: FYI, Boost has `overloaded_function`.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/functional/overloaded_function/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Actually, cppreference **does** mention this in it's [definition of the functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode it didn't when the question was posted, hence my comment after fixing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast an overloaded function pointer to disambiguate it:

```
function<int64_t(string const&)> obj =
  static_cast<int64_t(*)(string const&)>(stoll);
```

Edit: you also need to bind the default arguments, since `stoll` is a three-argument function and you are trying to make it take just one argument:

```
function<int64_t(string const&)> obj =
  std::bind(static_cast<int64_t(*)(string const&, size_t*, int)>(stoll),
    placeholders::_1, nullptr, 10);
```

Comment: sorry, but I get `error: address of overloaded function 'stoll' cannot be static_cast to type 'std::int64_t (*)(const std::string &, size_t *, int)'` with clang.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that.  I edited my answer with code that compiles.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a functor:

```
struct StringToLongLong {
    long long operator () (const std::string& s) const { return stoll(s); }
    long long operator () (const std::wstring& s) const { return stoll(s); }
};
std::function<std::int64_t(std::string const&)> obj = StringToLongLong();
```

Note: The functor might be locally defined in a function.

If the functor is no (!) local class in a function (See @MSalters comment):

```
struct StringToLongLong {
    template <typename String>
    long long operator () (const String& s) const { return stoll(s); }
};
std::function<std::int64_t(std::string const&)> obj = StringToLongLong();
```

Note: Member templates are invalid if the functor is locally defined in a function.

Comment: And if C++17 adds a Unicode overload, your struct is incomplete. Why not `template<typename STR> long long operator() (STR const& s) const() { return std::stoll(s); }` ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem for overload sets.  Written in C++1y as it saves a `decltype`

```
#define OVERLOAD_SET(F) struct {\
  template<typename...Args> auto operator()(Args&&...args)const{\
    return (F)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);\
  }\
}
```

now we can

```
static OVERLOAD_SET(std::stoll) os_stroll;
```

and `os_stroll` can be passed to `std::function` and it just does the right thing.

You can even enable ADL if you like:

```
#define ADL_OVERLOAD_SET(NS, F) struct {\
  template<typename...Args> auto operator()(Args&&...args)const{\
    using NS::F;
    return F(std::forward<Args>(args)...);\
  }\
}
```

Another optional improvement:

```
  /* cast to function pointer.  Copy paste for each calling convention */\
  template<typename R, typename Args...>\
  operator R(*)(Args...)() const {\
    return [](Args...args){return (F)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);};\
  }\
```

or be a bit more strict about what `Args...` to accept (the above will return a function pointer iff the types convert.  It should also probably do SFINAE to generate earlier failure).